# Can one AccessToken of facebook be used by multiple client

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, google-oauth

So I think this is very Valid Use case scenario.

So my application which is called ATP , is consist of multiple apps bind together .

My question is If I make the user login with one of these apps , Can I use that access token with the other apps as well.

So , I am believing if I use the same App Id and secret I think this should work . I have not tried anything yet so some help in this owuld be appreciated.

Thanks & regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. If you have right `Application ID` and `Application Secret` you can use this `access_token` wherever you want.

But I think you shouldn't, why? Because an user accepts one specific application to use his data, and he may not want to use it in other place.

But if we are talking only about coding, answer is simple: **yes**.